# Wrong InnerHTML path in wordpress site (Change logo)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to change the logo in a Wordpress site.
I am selecting to upload in the Media section and the image is uploaded
it is working when accessing the path from there.

But if I visit the site the image is not showing.
If I inspect element the image it shows that the path is wrong :
Why is the src path without the : ? how can I fix that ?

```
<a class="fusion-logo-link" href="http://localhost:8888/mysite">
    <img src="http://localhost8888/mysite/wp-content/uploads/logo.png" width="150" height="157" alt="my site" class="fusion-logo-1x fusion-standard-logo">
```

in Properties

```
host: "localhost:8888"
hostname: "localhost"
href: "http://localhost:8888/mysite"
hreflang: ""
id: ""
innerHTML: "↵   ↵   ↵   <img src="http://localhost8888/mysite/wp-content/uploads/logo.png" width="150" height="157" alt="my site" class="fusion-logo-1x fusion-standard-logo">↵ <img src="http://localhost8888/mysite/wp-content/uploads/logo.png" width="150" height="157" alt="my site" style="max-height: 157px; height: auto;" class="fusion-standard-logo fusion-logo-2x">↵    ↵   <!-- mobile logo -->↵   ↵   <!-- sticky header logo -->↵    "
innerText: ""
```

edit:

```
var $standard_logo_height = jQuery( '.fusion-standard-logo' ).height() + parseInt( jQuery( '.fusion-logo' ).data( 'margin-top' ) ) + parseInt( jQuery( '.fusion-logo' ).data( 'margin-bottom' ) );
        window.$initial_desktop_header_height = Math.max( window.$header_height, Math.max( $menu_height + $menu_border_height, $standard_logo_height ) + parseInt( jQuery( '.fusion-header' ).find( '.fusion-row' ).css( 'padding-top' ) ) + parseInt( jQuery( '.fusion-header' ).find( '.fusion-row' ).css( 'padding-bottom' ) ) );
        window.$sticky_can_be_shrinked = true;

        if( js_local_vars.sticky_header_shrinkage == '0' ) {
            $animation_duration = 0;
            window.$scrolled_header_height = window.$header_height;
        }
        if ( $logo ) {
            // Getting the correct natural height of the visible logo
            if ( $logo.hasClass( 'fusion-logo-2x' ) ) {
                var $logo_image = new Image();
                $logo_image.src = $logo( 'src' );
                window.original_logo_height = parseInt( $logo.height() ) + parseInt( js_local_vars.logo_margin_top ) + parseInt( js_local_vars.logo_margin_bottom );
            } else {
                // For normal logo we need to setup the image object to get the natural heights
                var $logo_image = new Image();
                $logo_image.src = $logo( 'src' );
                window.original_logo_height = parseInt( $logo_image.naturalHeight ) + parseInt( js_local_vars.logo_margin_top ) + parseInt( js_local_vars.logo_margin_bottom );

                // IE8, Opera fallback
                $logo_image.onload = function() {
                    window.original_logo_height = parseInt( this.height ) + parseInt( js_local_vars.logo_margin_top ) + parseInt( js_local_vars.logo_margin_bottom );
                };
            }
        }
```

The php

```
<?php if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'logo' ) ) : ?>
                <a class="fusion-logo-link" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                    <?php $logo_url = Avada_Sanitize::get_url_with_correct_scheme( Avada()->settings->get( 'logo' ) ); ?>

                    <?php if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'retina_logo_width' ) && Avada()->settings->get( 'retina_logo_height' ) ) : ?>
                        <?php $logo_size['width']  = Avada()->settings->get( 'retina_logo_width' ); ?>
                        <?php $logo_size['height'] = Avada()->settings->get( 'retina_logo_height' ); ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <?php $logo_size['width']  = ''; ?>
                        <?php $logo_size['height'] = ''; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <img src="<?php echo $logo_url; ?>" width="<?php echo $logo_size['width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $logo_size['height']; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" class="fusion-logo-1x fusion-standard-logo" />
                    <?php $retina_logo = Avada()->settings->get( 'logo_retina' ); ?>
                    <?php if ( $retina_logo ) : ?>
                        <?php $retina_logo = Avada_Sanitize::get_url_with_correct_scheme( $retina_logo ); ?>
                        <?php $style = 'style="max-height: ' . $logo_size['height'] . 'px; height: auto;"'; ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $retina_logo; ?>" width="<?php echo $logo_size['width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $logo_size['height']; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" <?php echo $style; ?> class="fusion-standard-logo fusion-logo-2x" />
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $logo_url; ?>" width="<?php echo $logo_size['width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $logo_size['height']; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" class="fusion-standard-logo fusion-logo-2x" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: please php section with refers your logo.

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: I included the php section

Comment: My guess would be that the fault lies in `Avada_Sanitize::get_url_with_correct_scheme`, and that it would work fine if you weren't running your site on a non-standard port (8888). The code there (which I'm guessing tries to do some clever things like using `https` for the scheme on a secure version of the site) probably just isn't expecting that. Lots of code like that in themes and plugins tends to break in that case, as people don't tend to test on non-standard ports.

Answer (score 0):

Is your logo's url hardcored? Check `header.php` and see if you can update the logo URL. If not, maybe you edited the `functions.php` file with custom logo src, so you should provide the code that has changed there.
Ifyou didn't modified anything in the template files, you might want to update from admin area  `Settings/General` the `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)`

Comment: Nothing in header file and functions. No I havent modified anything. It only happens for the logo. Wordpress address and site address are both localhost:8888/mysite